# Spring: How do I set the pattern of a @DateTimeFormat from a properties file?

Tags: spring, model, controller, annotations, datetime-format

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  I have a model that I submit to one of my controllers.  In it, is the following field

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "#{appProps['class.date.format']}")
private java.util.Date startDate;
```

However, the above doesn't work (the EL isn't being interpreted), in as far as every time I submit my form, I get an error.  If I use the following

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private java.util.Date startDate;
```

everything works fine.  But ideally, I'd like to drive the pattern from a properties file.  Is this possible and if so, what's the correct syntax?

- Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to read my system properties.  Then you can use this syntax to resolve placeholders : `${prop.name}`.

Your annotated filed should work like this then:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "${class.date.format}")
private java.util.Date startDate;
```

To configure your PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer for your application in xml, try this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:myProps.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolveablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Or, with JavaConfig:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    //note the static method! important!!
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource("myProps.properties")};
    configurer.setLocations(resources);
    configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return configurer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now it seems only to work with Property Placeholders.

Have a look at this:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8654