# Spring: how to set @DateTimeFormat pattern from a properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm posing the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17979137/225217) because the answers provided therein do not resolve my issue.

I'm using Spring 4.1.3 in a Spring MVC web application. I have a JPA entity bean containing the field:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "${date.format}")
private LocalDate certifiedOn;
```

I'd like the pattern to be injected based on a key in a properties file.  [This should work in Spring since 3.0.3](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7087), however the binding fails in the controller because the `Pattern includes reserved character '{'`.

I know that I am successfully reading my properties file as other properties are being used in the application.  Here is how I've got that setup via javaConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
@PropertySource("classpath:spring.properties")
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
  ...
}
```

At the root of the classpath sits the `spring.properties` file:

```
date.format = yyyy-MM-dd
```

What am I missing here that would prevent this from working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing this issue, and everything you're doing appears correct-- Here's what I have:

**application.properties**

```
date.format=yyyy-MM-dd
```

**Spring-managed class**

```
public class MyClass {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "${yyyy-MM-dd}")
private LocalDate certifiedOn = LocalDate.now();

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    log.info("Date format used: " + certifiedOn);
}
}
```

**Output**

> Date format used: 2015-01-22

**Notice**

I'm setting the field to `LocalDate.now()`, and it's showing the date in the proper format.

If I don't set the value of the `certifiedOn` field, then it prints out:

> Date format used: null

**Possible cause**

If the `null` value is what you're seeing in `certifiedOn`, perhaps it's getting `date.format` correctly from the properties file, but just hasn't been initialized to a non-null value yet.

Otherwise, everything you're describing here should work as advertised.  Perhaps there's another factor affecting what you're experiencing beyond what you're looking at?

Comment: Thanks, Cuga, I think you've helped me see the issue: you've labeled `MyClass` as a _Spring-managed_ class.  In my case, the class containing the `@DateTimeFormat` is a JPA entity bean and is _not_ managed by Spring.  This is a bit confusing, though, because Spring still scans this class for annotations and processes the `@DateTimeFormat` but perhaps as it is just an entity bean the Spring EL driven pattern cannot be properly injected.  Does this sound right?  Am I on the right track?

Comment: I should also mention that initializing the `LocalDate` attribute as you have shown did not resolve the issue.

Comment: On my machine, `MyClass` is really just a POJO, which is wired as a Bean in my Spring configuration (via annotations or XML config).

Comment: Can you try creating a new simple property in that same class, putting it in `spring.properties`, and seeing if the other property is being picked up?

Comment: Also-- is your class trying to access the variable before properties have been fully initialized?  Maybe look at implementing Spring's `InitializingBean` interface?

Comment: Yeah, I the issue is that my bean is not spring managed, it's created via hibernate (JPA).  When I attempted to inject a property like so: `@Transient @Value("${date.format}") private String dateFormat;` the result was null.  I think my next step is to figure out how to make an `@Entity` spring managed.  I've done something similar in the past by configuring a hibernate interceptor to load entities (by class) from spring rather than simply new them off.  I'll look into this.  It's a bummer that the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation doesn't allow for Spring EL patterns on non Spring-managed beans.